# Dart: Determine/Check list type at runtime

Tags: dart

If we test this,

```
print([1] is List<int>); // prints true
```

and if we test this,

```
List a = [1];
print(a is List<int>); // prints false
```

Which is technically correct as the List could get another type of object later.

Is there any way to determine the type of list by it's elements or will I need to use a loop to check the type of each element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong about the second example. The reason why the following returns `false` is because you are using `List` as type instead of using `var`, `final` or `List<int>`.

```
List a = [1];
print(a is List<int>); // prints false
```

Dart sees `List` as `List<dynamic>` in your example and will therefore make the type of the list to also contain `dynamic`:

```
List a = [1];
print(a is List<int>); // prints false
print(a.runtimeType); // List<dynamic>
```

But if you instead do let Dart automatically assign the type of the variable like:

```
final a = [1]; // or var
print(a is List<int>); // prints true
print(a.runtimeType); // List<int>
```

Then Dart will statically look at the content of the list when you are creating the list and assign the correct type.

The feature which reads `List` as `List<dynamic>` is called implicit-dynamic and will go away when non-nullable are introduced. You can also disable this feature right now if you follow this guide:

https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks

If you disable this feature you will get an error by the Dart analyzer:

> Missing type argument for list literal. Try adding an explicit type like 'dynamic', or enable implicit-dynamic in your analysis options file.

Comment: I don't mean to oppose you or anything but for the "You are wrong..." part, `List a = [1]; var s = a; print(s is List<int>);` still prints false. Please edit your answer or correct me if I am wrong. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: I'm actually accepting that List as a function parameter. So is there any way to free the List from that type or make it's type more dynamic in those regards (while checking)

Comment: The type of the List are defined when it is initialized and the type are hereafter on the object and will not change if you assign it to a variable of another type. Again, Dart are trying to be smart in your example by automatically make your code like: `List<dynamic> a = <dynamic>[1]`

Comment: Are you sure your method takes a List as argument and don't care about the type? Because you should properly write that method using generics. Can you provide an example of your method?